# Linux Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

On a multicore processor, if I create a subshell from a shell script file is there any chance for the subshell to go to another processor or will all the subshells and the parent shell will run in the same processor? I couldn't check on a multicore processor machine.

Comment: It could- but processes are not 'stuck' to processors (unless you go out of your way to pin it to one).  A process can change processors at the complete whim of the scheduler; regardless of its parent process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simultaneously existing processes may be executed on separate cores. Of course, this doesn't buy you anything unless the subshell is executed in the background with the main shell going on to do other work.

Comment: You can benefit if the sub-shell or command is part of a pipeline - then the multiple cores can each execute one part of the pipeline in parallel.  Of course, `sort` gums the works up a bit as it has to read all its input before it produces any output, but ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I've never experienced significant speedups from Unix pipelines on multicore hosts. The I/O overhead is just too large.